# How fixed positioned element gets all height

Tags: html, css, css-position

I try to understand why if i define div element and position it as fixed, to the left of the viewport, without define its height and without put some content into it, it gets all available height of the viewport?

I mean i use div, it is block element which gets its height according to its content (if not defined otherwise), in this case div does not have any content, how does it gets all the height ?

I tried to find it in the specification at 
[W3org](http://w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)
 but it doesn't say anything about it.

definition in HTML:

```
<div id="left"></div>
```

definition in CSS:

```
#left {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 20px;
z-index: 30;
left: 0;
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.69) 30%, rgba(88, 88, 88, 0.92));
```

}

Here is the link to the jsfiddle : [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bfgxnurz/)

If I define element as :

```
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
```

it gets height of the document.documentElement.clientHeight, which is much smaller, in my example, than body/html ? 
I really try to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Because you specify `top: 0` AND `bottom: 0`. Remove `bottom: 0`, and it will require a height.

For example in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bfgxnurz/1/).

Comment: I understand it , i just want to know why it happens? I tried to find it in the specification at w3org http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning but it doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'why it happens'. It happens because how else should the browser interpret a top and bottom position of `0`? Stick the element in the middle? It happens because that's how it's implemented. Just like why does `<strike>` make its contents struck-through?

Comment: It doesn't mentioned in any specification of the css, at least i can't find it. As i see it, it can be implemented different. That is why i'm asking why browsers implemented it this way?

Comment: How could it be implemented differently? You are telling it to place the top margin edge at the top of the screen and it's bottom margin edge at the bottom of the screen. That means it will take up the full height. [top](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/top) [bottom](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/bottom)

Comment: Exactly what @MatthewDarnell said. There is no other interpretation for this rule.

Comment: It doesn't happens the same way when you do this with position absolute. from w3org fixed definition : `The box's position is calculated according to the 'absolute' model...`

Comment: No, the height is the same for both `absolute` and `fixed`. However, when you define `absolute`, the element will be absolutely positioned, and will move as you scroll. When you specify `fixed`, its position is fixed and does not move, so it appears as though the height is the height of the page, but it isn't.